# try ... catch is not catching IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android

In an [open-source Camera App](https://github.com/crazymaik/remoteyourcam-usb), I have a crash at the following code

```
try {
    // crash happens in next line:
    PtpUsbConnection connection = new  PtpUsbConnection(usbManager.openDevice(device), in, out,
                      device.getVendorId(), device.getProductId());
    camera = new EosCamera(connection, listener, new WorkerNotifier(context));
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: camera was switched off? "+ e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Exception: camera was switched off? "+ e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

The crash produces the following log

```
02-25 10:41:14.698    9238-9238/com.remoteyourcam.usb E/UsbManager﹕ exception in UsbManager.openDevice
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: device /dev/bus/usb/001/008 does not exist or is restricted
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1469)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
        at android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager$Stub$Proxy.openDevice(IUsbManager.java:373)
        at android.hardware.usb.UsbManager.openDevice(UsbManager.java:308)
        at com.remoteyourcam.usb.ptp.PtpUsbService.connect(PtpUsbService.java:238)
        at com.remoteyourcam.usb.ptp.PtpUsbService.initialize(PtpUsbService.java:135)
        at com.remoteyourcam.usb.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:232)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5413)
        at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5469)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5474)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2945)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is a reproducible sequence of events which causes the crash. Specifically: *switching of the camera on the USB bus* when the App (apparently) does not foresee the possibility.

I was hoping to simply catch this Exception and then ignore it.

However, even though the code explicity catches `IllegalArgumentException` and also (for good measure) the general `Exception`, the App simply continues to crash.

**Why is my `IllegalArgumentException` not being caught?**

---- update:

The openDevice() method is part of Android Library. It actually seems to handle `Exception`.

Here are my imports

```
package com.remoteyourcam.usb.ptp;

import java.util.Map;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.remoteyourcam.usb.AppConfig;
import com.remoteyourcam.usb.ptp.Camera.CameraListener;
import com.remoteyourcam.usb.ptp.PtpCamera.State;
```

---- update 2:

This is the `openDevice()` implementation I see in Android 18. As far as I can tell, it handles a general `Exception`

```
/**
 * Opens the device so it can be used to send and receive
 * data using {@link android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest}.
 *
 * @param device the device to open
 * @return a {@link UsbDeviceConnection}, or {@code null} if open failed
 */
public UsbDeviceConnection openDevice(UsbDevice device) {
    try {
        String deviceName = device.getDeviceName();
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = mService.openDevice(deviceName);
        if (pfd != null) {
            UsbDeviceConnection connection = new UsbDeviceConnection(device);
            boolean result = connection.open(deviceName, pfd);
            pfd.close();
            if (result) {
                return connection;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "exception in UsbManager.openDevice", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: its in your opendevice method. you should add the try catch in that method

Comment: Show us your import statement(s).

Comment: Are you sure that exception was not cached? May be it was catched and printed by method `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The Log statement above it does not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exception is happening in another thread.

You are initializing and dispatching work to another thread asynchronously. Your code only catches exceptions in dispatching the Parcel to the remote Service.

For more information about remote procedure calls in Android you might want to read [Deep Dive into Binder](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1340/Deep_Dive_Into_Binder_Presentation.htm#slide-10).

Comment: OK. So there is nothing I can do at this point in the code. But could this exception be handled at the other thread?

Comment: I recon that it *should* be handled in UsbManager.openDevice() or throw an RemoteException back to your thread. Neither seems to be implemented.

Comment: I made the change to the `BroadcastReceiver` like @mach suggested, but the crash is still happening...

Comment: My bad, The PtpUsbService actually initiate a second remote call (That's the android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager$Stub$Proxy.openDevice)

Comment: I have noticed that `RemoteYourCamera` app does register when the camera is turned off. It generates a USB error. I could set a flag when such an error has occurred, and then test for that flag before calling `openDevice()`. Is that my best option?

Answer (score 0):

The same situation I got as you with this source code, I found a trick that avoid crash. Just fix your code

```
try {
    // crash happens in next line:
    PtpUsbConnection connection = new  PtpUsbConnection(usbManager.openDevice(device), in, out,
                      device.getVendorId(), device.getProductId());
    camera = new EosCamera(connection, listener, new WorkerNotifier(context));
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: camera was switched off? "+ e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Exception: camera was switched off? "+ e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

to

```
try {
    // crash happens in next line:
    UsbDeviceConnection udc = usbManager.openDevice(device);
    if (udc != null){
        PtpUsbConnection connection = new  PtpUsbConnection(udc, in, out,
                      device.getVendorId(), device.getProductId());
        camera = new EosCamera(connection, listener, new WorkerNotifier(context));
    }

}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: camera was switched off? "+ e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Exception: camera was switched off? "+ e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

It works for me!